# How can I get my canvas and Math.random() positions work together well?

Tags: javascript, html

I know, the title was very vague. I have this problem. I have a canvas with a width and a height. But when I am making "x" and "y" positions for these circles and rectangles, they don't exactly end up where I need them to. They will be off of the canvas.

Note: I think the answer is how I do my Math.random(). I might be making the ranges of what I want incorrectly.

Note: I haven't finished the code. I have barely started the rectangles and am still working on the "stop" and "start" buttons. The circles part (x and y positions) is what I need help with.

Javascript:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasWidth = 1024;
const canvasHeight = 576;

const circleCounter = document.querySelector('#circle-counter');
const rectangleCounter = document.querySelector('#rectangle-counter');

const start = document.querySelector('#start');
const stop = document.querySelector('#stop');

let rectCount = 0;
let circCount = 0;

function draw() {
    let circleId = setInterval(drawCircle, 500);
    //let rectangleId = setInterval(drawRectangle, 1000);
}

function drawCircle() {
    //Creates a random hex code
    let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    let color = "#" + randomColor;
    
    let radius = Math.round(Math.random() * 15 + 15);
    let diameter = 2 * radius;

    let centerX = Math.round(Math.random() * ((canvasWidth - diameter) - (0 + diameter)) + diameter);
    let centerY = Math.round(Math.random() * ((canvasHeight - diameter) - (0 + diameter)) + diameter);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();

    circCount++;
    circleCounter.innerHTML = circCount;
}

function drawRectangle() {
    let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    let color = "#" + randomColor;

    let rectangleWidth = Math.round(Math.random() * 15 + 15);
    let rectangleHeight = Math.round(Math.random() * 15 + 15);

    let cornerX = Math.round(Math.random() * (canvasWidth - 2 * rectangleWidth) + rectangleWidth);
    let cornerY = Math.round(Math.random() * (canvasHeight - 2 * rectangleHeight) + rectangleHeight);
}

function reset() {
    let confirmationStatement = confirm("Are you sure you want to reset?");

    if (confirmationStatement) {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Paint Splatter</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button id="start" onclick="draw()">Start</button>
            <button id="stop">Stop</button>
            <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>

        <div class="counter-display">
            <h2>Total Circles: <span id="circle-counter"></span></h2>
            <h2>Total Rectangles: <span id="rectangle-counter"></span></h2>
        </div>

        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am attempting to make a bunch of circles and rectangles appear onto a canvas at random positions with random colors and sizes. I am also trying to keep count of how many circles and rectangles there are.

Comment: If the positions are random, why would the position be 'wrong'? Can you describe what you're hoping to get vs what you are actually getting?

Comment: @Evert What I mean by "wrong" is that my centerX and centerY were set up in a way that I figured would keep the circles inside of the canvas, which it was not. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to set  width and height to your canas,and it must set on canvs tag not in your css

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasWidth = 1024;
const canvasHeight = 576;

const circleCounter = document.querySelector('#circle-counter');
const rectangleCounter = document.querySelector('#rectangle-counter');

let rectCount = 0;
let circCount = 0;
let circleId, rectangleId
function draw() {
    circleId = setInterval(drawCircle, 500);
    rectangleId = setInterval(drawRectangle, 1000);
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(circleId)
    clearInterval(rectangleId)
}
function drawCircle() {
    //Creates a random hex code
    let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    let color = "#" + randomColor;

    let radius = Math.round(Math.random() * 15 + 15);
    let diameter = 2 * radius;

    let centerX = Math.round(Math.random() * ((canvasWidth - diameter) - (0 + diameter)) + diameter);
    let centerY = Math.round(Math.random() * ((canvasHeight - diameter) - (0 + diameter)) + diameter);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();

    circCount++;
    circleCounter.innerHTML = circCount;
}

function drawRectangle() {
    let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    let color = "#" + randomColor;

    let rectangleWidth = Math.round(Math.random() * 15 + 15);
    let rectangleHeight = Math.round(Math.random() * 15 + 15);

    let cornerX = Math.round(Math.random() * (canvasWidth - 2 * rectangleWidth) + rectangleWidth);
    let cornerY = Math.round(Math.random() * (canvasHeight - 2 * rectangleHeight) + rectangleHeight);
}

function reset() {
    let confirmationStatement = confirm("Are you sure you want to reset?");

    if (confirmationStatement) {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
        <button id="start" onclick="draw()">Start</button>
        <button id="stop" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
        <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>

    <div class="counter-display">
        <h2>Total Circles: <span id="circle-counter"></span></h2>
        <h2>Total Rectangles: <span id="rectangle-counter"></span></h2>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="576"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of tinkering with my HTML and CSS and using the solution proposed by "moon", I have found the solution. All I had to do was create the height and width in the actual canvas tag of the HTML. What I had done was make the height and width in CSS. I don't know why it didn't work before necessarily, but it works now.

Javascript:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasWidth = 1024;
const canvasHeight = 576;

const circleCounter = document.querySelector('#circle-counter');

let circCount = 0;

function draw() {
    let circleId = setInterval(drawCircle, 250);
}

function drawCircle() {
    //Creates a random hex code
    let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    let color = "#" + randomColor;
    
    let radius = Math.round(Math.random() * 15 + 15);
    let diameter = 2 * radius;

    let centerX = Math.round(Math.random() * ((canvasWidth - diameter) - (0 + diameter)) + diameter);
    let centerY = Math.round(Math.random() * ((canvasHeight - diameter) - (0 + diameter)) + diameter);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();

    circCount++;
    circleCounter.innerHTML = circCount;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="buttons">
       <button id="start" onclick="draw()">Start</button>
       <button id="stop" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
       <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="counter-display">
       <h2>Total Circles: <span id="circle-counter"></span></h2>
    </div>
        
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="576"></canvas>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas {
    border: solid black 1px;
}

.counter-display h2 {
    font-size: 16pt;
}
```